# Prove True or false : If $A$ and $B$ are nxn invertible matrices and $(AB)^2=A^2B^2$, then $AB=BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

> Prove True or false : If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ invertible matrices and $(AB)^2=A^2B^2$, then $AB=BA$.

This looks like it is false, but the thing is I can't find a counter example for it.

Comment: What happens when you expand both sides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Multiply $(AB)^2=A^2B^2$ on the left by $A^{-1}$ and on the right by ...

Comment: Ummmmmmmmm, also by A-1, and on which side since the order matters?

Comment: @Sal: The order matters, and multiplying on the right by $A^{-1}$ won’t help. Have you actually tried multiplying on the left by $A^{-1}$ and looking at the result to see what’s been accomplished towards showing that $BA=AB$?

Comment: I'm so confused, if I time it by the inverse, then how would I reduce that expression?

Comment: @Sal: $A^{-1}(AB)^2=A^{-1}ABAB$; what does $A^{-1}A$ simplify to?

Comment: Um the identity matrix, IBAB, so BAB

Comment: @Sal: Right, so on the left you now have $BAB$. And when you multiply $A^2B^2$ on the left by $A^{-1}$, you get ... ?

Comment: IAB^2 so ABB and then BAB≠ABB?

Comment: @Sal: Why $\ne$? You were given that $(AB)^2=A^2B^2$, so $A^{-1}(AB)^2=A^{-1}A^2B^2$. That means that $BAB=ABB$. Now multiply by something on the right to show that $BA=AB$.

Comment: Shah! By B-1, that ll make the expression true! Thanks a lot, I appreciate your step by step guide through

Comment: @Sal: :-) Yep, it’s true. You’re welcome!